# Can't insert into database in R

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I'm having problems creating and inserting a small dataframe into mysql.
This is something I've done before but for some reason it just gives me error.

```
library("RMySQL");
mylocaldb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='myuser', password='mypass', dbname='mydb', host='192.168.1.101')
dbWriteTable(mylocaldb, value=mydataframe, name="data1" , row.names = F , append = F , overwrite = T )
```

I have `mydataframe` with 4 fields and `data1` is created in the database, but nothing is inserted.

Here is the error message:

```
Error in dbFetch(rs, n = -1, ...) : 
corrupt resultSet, missing fieldDescription
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me with what I might be doing wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe relevant issue: https://github.com/rstats-db/RMySQL/issues/140

Comment: Can you replicate this issue with a local instance of MySQL? Does MySQL user have permission to make DDL changes? What are the names of dataframe columns?

Comment: I think the issue with the RStudio server edition. I switched to the desktop version and that solved the issue.